# Since JPEG files are stored in big endian format, how does a little endian machine read it correctly?

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture, endianness

Since JPEG files are stored as a big endian then a little machine reads it in reverse order.
How does a little endian machine correct it?

Answer (score 1):

Software on a little endian processors can call functions to convert big endian integers to little endian integers.  These functions are common - integers sent over IP networks are sent in big-endian order.

On Unix based machines (Linux, Mac OS X, FreeBSD, etc.) there are functions like ntohs and ntohl to convert integers from network/big endian order to host order.  On little-endian machines these functions do the necessary byte swapping.  On big endian machines they do nothing.  This allows code to be written which works on both big and little endian machines.

Comment: most architectures have an instruction for reversing endian, so `ntohl` and `ntohs` and its counterpart may result in just one instruction or nothing

Comment: There are also functions swap(a,b); and swab(a,b);